# FreeImage include in c

Tags: c, image, compilation, compiler-errors, freeimage

Is there any way to include http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/index.html in my c test program without first installing the library? It fails to compile because of some memset..

Here is my C code. Is there any way to make it work? Please try compiling it and tell me how to do it if it works?

```
#define NAZIV_DATOTEKE 50
#include <stdio.h>
#include "FreeImage.h"


void FreeImageErrorHandler(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif, const char *message);
FIBITMAP* GenericLoader(const char* lpszPathName, int flag);

int main(){
    FreeImage_Initialise();
    FIBITMAP *dib, *ptr;
    char ulaz_slika[NAZIV_DATOTEKE] = "bmp_24.bmp";
    char izlaz_slika[NAZIV_DATOTEKE] = "free.bmp";  //podrazumevana vrednost

    dib = GenericLoader(ulaz_slika, 0);
    //slika = FreeImage_Load(FIF_BMP, "bmp_24.bmp", BMP_DEFAULT);
    FreeImage_SetOutputMessage(FreeImageErrorHandler);
    if (dib) {
        printf("Ucitan \"%s\".\n", ulaz_slika);
    }

    FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FreeImage_GetFileType(ulaz_slika, 0);
    if ((fif != FIF_BMP) && (fif != FIF_ICO) && (fif != FIF_JPEG) && (fif != FIF_PNG) && (fif != FIF_TIFF)){
        printf("Format slike nije podrzan.\n");
        return 1;
    }


    ptr = FreeImage_ConvertTo24Bits(dib);
    FreeImage_SetOutputMessage(FreeImageErrorHandler);
    FreeImage_Unload(dib);
    FreeImage_SetOutputMessage(FreeImageErrorHandler);
    dib = ptr;
    if (dib) {
        printf("Konvertovan u RGB.\n");
    }


    const char *slika = (const char*)FreeImage_GetBits(dib);


    if (FreeImage_Save(fif, dib, izlaz_slika, BMP_DEFAULT)) {
        printf("Snimljen \"%s\".\n", izlaz_slika);
    }


    if (dib) {
        FreeImage_Unload(dib);
    }
    FreeImage_DeInitialise();
    return 0;
}

void FreeImageErrorHandler(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif, const char *message){
    printf("\n*** ");
    if(fif != FIF_UNKNOWN) {
        if (FreeImage_GetFormatFromFIF(fif))
            printf("%s Format\n", FreeImage_GetFormatFromFIF(fif));
    }
    printf(message);
    printf(" ***\n");
}

FIBITMAP* GenericLoader(const char* lpszPathName, int flag) {
    FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FIF_UNKNOWN;
    // check the file signature and deduce its format
    // (the second argument is currently not used by FreeImage)
    fif = FreeImage_GetFileType(lpszPathName, 0);
    if(fif == FIF_UNKNOWN) {
        // no signature ?
        // try to guess the file format from the file extension
    fif = FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilename(lpszPathName);
    }
    // check that the plugin has reading capabilities ...
    if((fif != FIF_UNKNOWN) && FreeImage_FIFSupportsReading(fif)) {
        // ok, let's load the file
        FIBITMAP *dib = FreeImage_Load(fif, lpszPathName, flag);
        // unless a bad file format, we are done !
        return dib;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot.  To compile your source, the linker needs the library.

Comment: Or more specifically, either the compiler needs the header files to compile your C code or the linker needs the library to link your object files

Comment: You are wrong. The dynamic link libraries will allow to do exactly what he wants.

Comment: The compiler needs the library to correct resolve symbols and map the address of the library function. Depending on your compiler and the target operating system, you can choose dynamic linking. Which in turn will load the latest version of the library on the system.